# The Progress Icon bar it doesn't show up?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lottie

When I click confirm button to take me to success screen the progress bar and done icon it doesn't show up please help

Success screen code

```
const Success =({navigation})=>{

  const [lottiFinished, setLottiFinished] = useState(false)

  const onAnimationFinish =()=>{

       setLottiFinished(true)
       setTimeout(()=>{
       navigation.navigate('Delivery')
    },4000)
  }
     

    return(
        <View style={{
            flex:1,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
            backgroundColor:COLORS.grey
        }}>
     {!lottiFinished?
      <LottieView 
           source={images.progress}
           autoPlay
           loop={false}
           onAnimationFinish={onAnimationFinish}
           style={{
            height:60,
            width:100
           }}
      
      />
      :
      <View style={{
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
       }}>
          <LottieView
            autoPlay
            loop={false} 
            source={images.done}
            style={{height:200,width:"60%"}}
      />

           <Text style={{
                   marginTop:SIZES.base,
                   ...FONTS.h1,
                   fontWeight:'bold'
      }}
           >Congratulations!</Text>
           <Text style={{
            marginTop:SIZES.base,
            color:COLORS.darkColor,
            ...FONTS.body2,
            fontWeight:'500'
           }}>Payment was successfully made</Text>
         </View>
     }
        </View>
    )
}
```

I'm using lottiview library and I don't know why the progress bar and done icon doesn't work in this code.Anyone has idea please assist out and your help is highly considered